# Inequation solving. $\frac{(x+2)²}{x+1}<4$

Tags: inequality

I am trying to solve this inequality, but I always get the wrong score. This is how I did it.

$$
\frac{(x+2)^2}{x+1}<4\\
(x+2)^2< 4(x+1)\\
(x+2)^2 < 4x+4\\
x^2+4x+4 < 4x+4\\
x^2+4x+4-4x-4 < 0\\
x^2<0\\
x<0
$$

I know that I should get $x<-1$ but I always get $0$. What is my mistake???

Thanks

Comment: The first multiplication can be wrong. if x+1 is negative you must invert the inequality

Comment: $x^2 < 0 \not\Rightarrow x < 0$. In fact, on $\mathbb{R}$, it implies that $x$ cannot exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes like this

$$
\frac{(x+2)²}{x+1}<4\\
(x+2)² < 4(x+1),\space x+1>0 \space or \space (x+2)² > 4(x+1),\space x+1<0\\
(x+2)² < 4x+4, \space x>-1 \space or \space (x+2)² > 4x+4, \space x<-1\\
x²+4x+4 < 4x+4, \space x>-1 \space or \space x²+4x+4 > 4x+4, \space x<-1\\
x²+4x+4-4x-4 < 0, \space x>-1 \space or \space x²+4x+4-4x-4 > 0, \space x<-1\\
x²<0, x>-1 \space (impossible)\space or \space x^2>0, x<-1\\
x<-1
$$

EDIT:
There is another method:
$$
\frac{(x+2)²}{x+1}<4\\
\frac{(x+2)²}{x+1}-4 < 0\\
\frac{(x+2)²-4x-4}{x+1} < 0\\
\frac{x^2+4x+4-4x-4}{x+1} < 0\\
\frac{x^2}{x+1}<0
$$
Since $x^2>0$ for any rational $x$, the sign depends only in $x+1$.
 When x+1 negtive ($x<-1$), the expression is negative, and when it is positive ($x>-1$) the expression is potitive.

Answer (score 1):

simply write the expression as -

$ {(x+1)^2 - 4(x+1)}$ / $ x+1 $ < 0

=> $x^2/x+1 $ < 0

here $ x^2 $ is always positive .

=> $ x+1 < 0 $   => $x < -1 $.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{(x+2)^2}{x+1}<4
\implies\dfrac{(x+2)^2}{x+1}-4<0
\implies\dfrac{(x+2)^2-4(x+1)}{x+1}<0
\implies\dfrac{x^2}{x+1}<0$

$x^2$ can't be less than zero so the only solution is $x+1<0 \implies x<-1$.